# Move each div with same class into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got 2 divs with the same class and I am trying to move each of the 2 divs into a different div.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".pac-container").prependTo("#gp-content");
}, 500);
```

```css
.pac-container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#wrapper1,
#wrapper2 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pac-container"></div>
<div class="pac-container"></div>

<div id="wrapper1"></div>
<div id="wrapper2"></div>
```

My goal is now to move the first `pac-container` into `#wrapper1` and the second `pac-container` into `#wrapper2`. The `pac-container` are sitting next to each other at the html-markup and each `#wrapper` sits on different positions at the html-markup.

---

### Goal

```
<div id="wrapper1">
<div class="pac-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2">
<div class="pac-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it by referencing the `.pac-container` elements explicitly by index using `eq()`:

```js
var $pac = $('.pac-container');
$pac.eq(0).prependTo('#wrapper1');
$pac.eq(1).prependTo('#wrapper2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pac-container">PAC container 1</div>
<div class="pac-container">PAC container 2</div>

<div id="wrapper1">wrapper1 </div>
<div id="wrapper2">wrapper2</div>
```

However, this is not very DRY. You could instead use a common class on the wrapper elements, then relate them to the containers by index, something like this:

```js
$('.pac-container').each(function(i) {
  $(this).prependTo($('.wrapper').eq(i));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pac-container">PAC container 1</div>
<div class="pac-container">PAC container 2</div>

<div class="wrapper">wrapper1 </div>
<div class="wrapper">wrapper2</div>
```

Comment: I like your first solution, cause the destination wrappers can have different ids and this is what I need and works for me best. But the other soution works too if u got other conditions. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `.pac-container` and move then individually.

Here in example, I have added `wrapper` class to use common selector and use `.eq()` to target the element.

```js
$('.pac-container').each(function(i){
  $(this).appendTo($('.wrapper').eq(i))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pac-container">1</div>
<div class="pac-container">2</div>

<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper1"></div>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper2"></div>
```

Comment: Works great if u add a class to your wrappers ;)

Answer (score 1):

To move an element use [detach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_detach.asp) and `appendTo()` Try this:

```js
$(".pac-container").each(function(i){
    $(this).detach().appendTo($(".wrapper").eq(i))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pac-container">pac-container1</div>
<div class="pac-container">pac-container2</div>

<div class="wrapper">wrapper1</div>
<div class="wrapper">wrapper2</div>
```